# How can I find out which processes are using or listening on which network interfaces?

Tags: network-interface, socket

`ifconfig` lists several network interfaces, some of which are virtual ones.

How can I find out which processes are using or listening on which network interfaces?  Thanks.

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a6:79:a6:bc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xfc400000-fc420000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3102389  bytes 174723039 (174.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3102389  bytes 174723039 (174.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:b1:aa:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 708  bytes 68468 (68.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 316  bytes 51806 (51.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe99:5eee  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:54:00:99:5e:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 257  bytes 28494 (28.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23514  bytes 1240204 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.97  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6   prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 80:1f:02:b5:c3:89  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1269625  bytes 1045069752 (1.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 646600  bytes 101897054 (101.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Network Interface? They're listening on addresses, or say holding an opened socket, if on POSIX system.

Answer (score 1):

`ss -plnt` will list `p`rocesses `l`istening `n`umerically on `t`cp ports and will show you the IP and port bound to, as well as relevant PIDs and file descriptors:

```
$ sudo ss -plnt | grep -E ':(22|8384)[^0-9]'
LISTEN   0         128            192.168.42.2:8384             0.0.0.0:*        users:(("syncthing",pid=14565,fd=8))
LISTEN   0         128                 0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*        users:(("sshd",pid=6099,fd=3))
LISTEN   0         128                    [::]:22                  [::]:*        users:(("sshd",pid=6099,fd=4))
```

Compare the same from the older `netstat -plnt`:

```
$ sudo netstat -plnt | grep -E ':(22|8384)[^0-9]'
tcp        0      0 192.168.42.2:8384       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14565/syncthing
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6099/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      6099/sshd
```

Shown are the secure shell daemon (listening on all interfaces), and my local install of SyncThing (which has its management interface is bound explicitly to one network address).

Comment: Strange ss -plnt did not show ssh for me, but netstat does.

Comment: Try looking for the numerical port:  `ss -plnt | grep ':22'`.

Comment: netstat looks better! Is it being deprecated? ( I always used it, never heared about ss replacing it, I thinked it is just an alternative, seems that every alternative in Linux are replacing the old ones )

Comment: I prefer `netstat` as well, though admittedly largely due to familiarity from long usage.  As to the why of it?  That is beyond my pay-grade.